# HttpPost and HttpRequest multiple responses

Tags: java, android

I have a Http Post

```
            try {
            String response1 = null;
            response1 = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(
                    "http://giveaway.synamegames.com/appfiles/login.php",
                    postParameters);
            String res = response1.toString();
            // res = res.trim();
            res = res.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
            if (res.equals("2350") && checkboxv.equals("1")) {
                Intent login = new Intent(this, MainMenuActivity.class);
                login.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                startActivity(login);
                SavePreferences("lu", et_username.getText().toString());
                SavePreferences("lp", et_pass.getText().toString());
                SavePreferences("cbauto", "1");
            } else if (res.equals("2350") && checkboxv.equals("0")) {
                Intent login = new Intent(this, MainMenuActivity.class);
                login.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                startActivity(login);
                SavePreferences("lu", "");
                SavePreferences("lp", "");
                SavePreferences("cbauto", "0");
            } else if (res.equals("1000")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Incorrect version. Please update.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (res.equals("588")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Incorrect Password or Username.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "Server Error. Please try again later.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
```

If my response is 1000, 2350, etc. it'll give the android phone a specific response. However I want my database to give android database information. In my situation I have
players register and enter in their name, email, username, and password. Upon login I want the phone to retrieve the name the user assigned when they created their account. For security reasons I can't store this information on the phone. I could have multiple HTTP Posts but that would just slow the application down. My question is...

Is there any possible way I can retrieve multiple responses and put those responses into different Strings without having to do another http post?

Comment: Are you saying basically after the successful login, you need to make another http call to get the user's name that they are registering with?

Comment: yup, i would also need to get the other information they would have inputted during their registeration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are designing the server side also, what I would do is basically returning the profile information as part of the response in JSON format. You could use [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) from Android to parse the JSON response from your server. So your response String for successful login would look like

```
{
    "response" : {
        "responseCode" : 2350,
        "userProfile" : {
            "name" : "Me",
            "email" : "me@me.com"
        }
    }
}
```

And for failed response

```
{
    "response" : {
        "responseCode" : 588
    }
}
```

This way, you don't have to make 2 http calls and would save you from another trip to the server

Comment: Could you give me an example of how I would code the php? Just echo?
Better yet a more precise showing of how the code would look. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, pretty much just echo at the very basic of it. You might want to leverage JSON PHP library http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php and especially json_encode http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php. Plenty of examples in the comments to get you going